# Curl request returns no data on localhost but no curl_errno. Works ok on web server

Tags: php, curl

Just a short block of code to test the acquisition of data from a remote server.

```
<?php
// get the event list for this PT
$pt = 'PT745';
$url = 'https://website.com/v1/events? 
tags='.$pt.'&start=gt2018-08-01';
// Create a curl handle
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    echo '<br>Data collection failed!';
    } else {
    echo '<br>Data collected.';
    // echo $data;
}    
curl_close($ch);  
?>
```

On my localhost the phrase 'Data collection failed' gets printed but no curl_errno and the variable $data is empty.   The whole block works perfectly on my web server!

Comment: Try to curl from a local terminal to see if there are any errors.

Comment: I think `https` issue. Localhost does not contain `https` and your CURL url contain `https`. So I think it is issue of ssl.

Comment: My localhost has SSL enabled.

Comment: This seems to be server related.   Using Wampserver I get the problem.   Change to Xampp and all works as expected.